# wordpress: let subscribers submit content to post ( yes / no, radio buttons )

Tags: wordpress

i'm currently struggeling with finding the right way for a function in wordpress.
there are many subscribers who should be able to say "yes" or "no" to a post.

until now, i added some more fields to the comments template.
but its not the right way because of empty comments, its like raping the comments function.

the point is: how to let subscribers (or any other role) submit content (like a comment) to a post?

is there any other way than the_content & the_comment, user specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom form and after submission add data in database in wp_postmeta table.

For example `
 get data from form

$data  = array();
 $data['user_id'] = $user->ID; // current user id
 $data['post_id']  = $_POST['post_id']; // post id which you will receive after form submission
 $data['answer'] = $_POST['answer']; // this is your radio button value yes or now

You can serialize $data or you can keep it as json in database.

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_key`,`meta_value`) VALUES ('user_vote', $serialized_data);

Best Regards,
Davit.

Comment: thx @davit ! i see, there is a way. but first, i need to dive into that wp_postmeta thing. is there any smart tutorial somewhere?

Comment: You can look here there is nested function for it http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta